# Drupal hook that runs when modules are installed and uninstall?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-hooks

I am trying to get a Drupal to run a custom hooks; one that needs to run when a module is being installed and another for when the module is being unistalled. Is there a hook or a trigger that I can use to have Drupal run the hook while the module is installing or uninstalling? The hook that I need to run builds taxonomy terms from an array. I am basing the lay out on the hook_schema. An example of the implementation of this hook is:

```
function mymodule_install_taxonomy() {
    return array(
         <<Taxonomy Structure Here>>
    );
}
```

This code would be placed in the .install file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your own module is installed or for others?

For your own, there is [hook_install()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) (only called the first time your module is installed, usually used to install the schema defined in hook_schema() in Drupal 6, this is automated in Drupal 7), [hook_uninstall()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_uninstall/7), [hook_enable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7) (called every time your module is enabled) and finally [hook_disable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_disable/7) (when your module is disabled).

Drupal 7 has also added a similar set of hooks that is however called when *other* modules are installed, uninstalled, enabled or disabled, see [hook_modules_*()](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/hook_modules_)

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. Also it was for when other modules were installed.